# Ubuntu 12.04 broke Mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu-12.04, mysql2

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and my (production!) Rails app went down hard.

I'm in a hurry trying to fix it while my site is just totally down.

```
A source file that the application requires, is missing.
It is possible that you didn't upload your application files correctly. Please check whether all your application files are uploaded.
A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.
Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file.     Please check it in order to analyse the problem.
Error message:
libmysqlclient_r.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /domains/myapp.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
```

I tried `sudo gem install mysql2`, but it didn't change anything. Please help! I have no idea what's wrong and my app is displaying stack traces to my users in the meantime! Thank you for any ideas you may have!

I have a hunch that this may be a path issue. For example, I tried `cd`-ing my way to that `mysql2.so` missing file and found a strange message:

```
cd /domains/myapp.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
deploy@myserver:/domains/myapp.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems$ cd mysql2-0.3.11/
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@mysql2': Permission denied
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p0@mysql2: Permission denied
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0 with gemset mysql2
deploy@myserver:/domains/myapp.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11$ pwd
/domains/myapp.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11
deploy@myserver:/domains/myapp.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11$ ls -l
```

Those messages were bizarre in and of themselves. Does `cd` usually trigger a `mkdir`? Does this somehow suggest that the file exists but I need to add a path to it somehow?

Comment: Ok, first, relax. Breathe. It's going to be alright. Would it be possible to bring the app temporarily to prevent stack traces from being shown?

Comment: I hope this serves as a reminder why a proper deployment infrastructure would have a staging server that's configured as closely as possible to the production environment. You would've seen this coming if you had a place to test it. Even a [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) instance is a great place to start.

Comment: @tadman, that's a great suggestion. I'm just a humble team-of-one doing this site unpaid out of love, so a fully legit deployment infrastructure may be beyond me, but VirtualBox is a great tip and I will definitely look into it, thanks!

Comment: A full deployment infrastructure doesn't have to be expensive or hard to set up. A 2GB VM is usually a reasonable example to test against and VirtualBox is free so there's no excuses to not use it. To help manage your instances you could try [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/). A solo team needs as much automation as they can get.

Comment: Thank you very much for these! Needless to say I will investigate them just as soon as I put these fires out. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need to redeploy your application and rebuild your gems with system dependencies. Installing the gem system-wide isn't going to help. This is indicated because `shared/bundle` is in the path.

Comment: I tried redeploying from Capistrano and got the same issue: `rake aborted!` `libmysqlclient_r.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /domains/myapp.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so`

Comment: I tried rebuilding gems using `gem pristine --all --no-extensions` but no dice, same issue.

Comment: You might want to temporarily rename `/domains/myapp.com/shared/bundle` to something else and see if a new deploy will rebuild that directory from scratch. Your existing `mysql2` gem is linked against a library that no longer exists, but it's considered "installed" so it won't be touched on subsequent deploys. If it works, delete the old `bundle` directory.

Comment: tadman! You are a genius! You are my new personal hero. Thank you a million times over, and rest assured I will be following all of your preventative advice from now forward. You have my immense gratitude.